# Excel logic - finding missing parts

Tags: excel, logic, excel-formula

I need to use excel to find the missing parts. As you can see, the "Part" column is the common link. The logic is if there is any "Compatible" item created in the series of the same "Parts", check if there are any missing Compatible items by comparing the item column. As you can see, Compatible items end with the "OCP" string and the OEM items do not. Otherwise they are the same thing. Any ideas? There are 13,000 lines I need to check for this.

[image: Excel List]

In the above example we can see there are many OEM versions of the items missing.

Comment: Have you tried using `VLOOKUP`s?

Comment: No because I don't know how to write the function correctly. A regular vlookup wouldn't suffice. Ideally I would like Excel to create a new blank row where every new OEM or Compatible item would need to be added

Comment: In essence you want a filtered list of all parts without OCP on the end? and if they aren't listed you want to include them?

Comment: You can't create new rows using a formula.  You'd have to use a macro for that.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. There are no missing "Parts" since all the "Parts" are the same. What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

1. in a new column, add a formula like this:

   ```
   =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE($A2;"OCP";"");$A:$A;0));"ok";"missing")
   ```
2. autofilter this column for missing values
3. copy filtered rows
4. paste them after the last item
5. while having these new rows selected, replace (Ctrl+H) Compatible with OEM
6. sort if you need to

optionally, record these steps as a macro..